# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined contact form html

Tags: javascript, html

I'v made a contact form in HTML, The code that was written is supposed to if the form is filled out correctly, change the button from "submit enquiry" to "processing..."
The code works when I test it using dreamweaver but when i try it on wordpress using the DIVI theme im getting errors

```
function change()                                    
{ 
var salutation = document.forms["testform"]["salutation"]; 
var firstname = document.forms["testform"]["firstname"];
var lastname = document.forms["testform"]["lastname"];
var email = document.forms["testform"]["email"];
var phone = document.forms["testform"]["phone"];
var address = document.forms["testform"]["address1"];
var state = document.forms["testform"]["state"];
var zipcode = document.forms["testform"]["zipcode"];
var comments = document.forms["testform"]["comments"];
var custentity_stiltz_where_did_you_hear = document.forms["testform"] 
["custentity_stiltz_where_did_you_hear"];
if (salutation.value == "")                                  
{
    window.alert("fill in")
    salutation.focus()
    return false; 
} 

if (firstname.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 

} 

if (lastname.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
} 

if (email.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
}   

if (phone.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
} 


if (address.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
} 

if (state.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
}


if (zipcode.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
}

if (comments.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
}

if (custentity_stiltz_where_did_you_hear.value == "")                                  
{
    return false; 
}
var elem = document.getElementById("buttonscriptcpf");
if (elem.value=="Submit Enquiry") elem.value = "Processing...";
else elem.value = "Submit Enquiry";
return true; 
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: What line gives the error? There are a lot of times you access an element's `.value` property; it could be any one of those.

Comment: All of them, if I remove salutation.value portion of the script so firstname.value is at the top I get the same error.

Comment: So if all of the variables end up undefined, you need to check how you're initializing/assigning them. Check that your `document.forms` method is referring to what you want by stepping through your code in Chrome's developer tools.